# Extract words from one df column, assign to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two columns in a dataframe: Pests and `FieldComment`. If the value of Pests is listed as 'None', then I'd like to search the `FieldComment` column for specific words and overwrite what's in the Pests column. If none of the words are found in the `FieldComment` column, the Pests column can remain as 'None'.

Example:

```
pests_list = ['Spiders', 'Rodents', 'Ants', 'Honey Bees']
```

| Pests | FieldComment |
| --- | --- |
| Spiders | Performed service. |
| None | Performed service for reported rodents. |

The above would ideally turn into this:

| Pests | FieldComment |
| --- | --- |
| Spiders | Performed service. |
| Rodents | Performed service for reported rodents. |

This is what I've tried so far but I can't quite get it:

```
for w in df['FieldComment'].str.split():
    for p in pests_list:
        if w.str.lower() == p.str.lower():
            df['Pests'] = p
```

I've also tried:

```
df.loc[df['Pests'] == 'None', "Pests"] =  *[pest for pest in pest_list if pest in df['FieldComment']]
```

And finally:

```
df.loc[df['Pests'] == 'None', "Pests"] = df.loc[df['Pests'] == 'None', "Pests"].apply(lambda x: pest for pest in pest_list if pest in df['FieldComment'] else 'None')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert the pests `list` into a `set`.
2. Create a `set` with the words from `FieldComment`.
3. Get the intersection of both `set`s and fill column `Pests` where it is null.

```
pests_set = set([p.lower() for p in pests_list])

df.loc[df["Pests"].isna(), "Pests"] = df["FieldComment"].apply(
    lambda x: ", ".join(
        set(x.strip(".").lower().split()).intersection(pests_set)
    ).capitalize()
)
```

```
     Pests                             FieldComment
0  Spiders                       Performed service.
1  Rodents  Performed service for reported rodents.
```

---

This solution will join pest names with `,` if there is more than one in the `FieldComment` column. For this dataframe:

```
     Pests                                FieldComment
0  Spiders                          Performed service.
1     None  Performed service for rodents and spiders.
```

Result would be:

```
              Pests                                FieldComment
0           Spiders                          Performed service.
1  Spiders, rodents  Performed service for rodents and spiders.
```

---

Note that if the dataframe has a `str` `'None'`, and not the `None` keyword, you would have to modify the above code slightly, replacing `df["Pests"].isna()` with `df["Pests"] == 'None'`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is just iterate over all values in `pests_list` and search the first occurrence in the string.

```py
pests_list = ["Spiders", "Rodents", "Ants", "Honey Bees"]

mask = df["Pests"].isna()

df.loc[mask, "Pests"] = [
    next((p for p in pests_list if p.lower() in c), None)
    for c in df.loc[mask, "FieldComment"].str.lower()
]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Pests                             FieldComment
0  Spiders                       Performed service.
1  Rodents  Performed service for reported rodents.
2     None              Nothing will be found here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a regular expression from the pests list and use `str.extract` like so:

```py
import re
pests_re = rf"({'|'.join(pests_list)})"
df["Pests"] = df.Pests.fillna(
    df.FieldComment
    .str.extract(
        pests_re, 
        flags=re.I, # case insensitive 
        expand=False # output as Series
    )
)
```